# Using the useContext , it says object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, state, react-context

When ever i am using useContext in the js file, it gives the error "TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))". Removing that line , it works perfectly fine . I am not able to figure out the problem with this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./login.css";
import { loginCall } from "../../apicalls";
import { useContext } from "react";
import {AuthContext} from '../../context/AuthContext.js'

export default function Login() {
  const email = useRef();
  const password = useRef();

  const [user,dispatch] = useContext(AuthContext);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // loginCall(
    //   { email: email.current.value, password: password.current.value },
    //   dispatch
    // );
    console.log('hi');
  };
  // console.log(user);
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="loginWrapper">
        <div className="loginLeft">
          <h3 className="loginLogo">SocioFolio</h3>
          <span className="loginDesc">
            Connect with friends and the world around you on SocioFolio.
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="loginRight">
    <form action="" 
    onSubmit={handleClick}
    >
          <div className="loginBox">
            <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required className="loginInput" />
            <input placeholder="Password" type="password" required minLength="6" className="loginInput" />
            <button className="loginButton">Log In</button>
            <span className="loginForgot">Forgot Password?</span>
            <button className="loginRegisterButton">
              Create a New Account
            </button>
          </div>
    </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share `AuthContext`?

Comment: Sure @OkanKaradag

Comment: Could it be a problem in `LoginCall`?

Comment: No, even though i am replacing it with console log , its still behaving the same